# Can't connect to website with LetsEncrypt certificate - nginx

Tags: django, nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'd like to add ssl certificate to my django app. I've followed [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04) so the nginx config for domain was changed but now it looks like generated certificate is incorrect.

nginx conf before certbot modifications

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name doamin.com www.domain.com;


    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/poul3r/doamin.com;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

and after certbot action

```
server {
    server_name doamin.com www.doamin.com;


    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/poul3r/doamin.com;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }



    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/doamin.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/doamin.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}



server {
    if ($host = doamin.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name doamin.com www.doamin.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

What I'm doing wrong or what could went wrong during letsencypt implementation ?

Comment: What do you see in your nginx logs (error and access logs)?

Comment: @dirkgroten log from nginx errors log file looks like "[error] 15715#15715: *73 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: X.X.X.X, server: 0.0.0.0:443" (X.X.X.X - my computer ip). What does it mean? There is key file behind "/etc/letsencrypt/live/doamin.com/fullchain.pem" path. All cert files whas generated and exist.

Answer (score 0):

I've already found solution for this problem. Based info from [solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/844161/ssl-ngnix-no-ssl-certificate-is-defined-in-server-listening-on-ssl-port-whi) I realized, there is one more app on nginx that does not have ssl certification but redirect to 443. When I changed theirs config to listen only on 80, first domain works correctly.